# Why do I get a PATH error when sourcing RVM?

Tags: macos, path, terminal, rvm, environment-variables

When starting up terminal or using RVM I keep getting this error. I have tried removing the PATH and I still get nothing.

```
cat: /Users/admin/.rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
    Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin' is not available,
             usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
             it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
             to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247'.
    -bash: /Users/admin/.rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
    -bash: /Users/admin/.rvm/scripts/help: No such file or directory
```

My ~/.bash_profile, edited for brevity:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

### You're Clobbering Your PATH

You need to source RVM *after* any PATH customizations, or you're just clobbering the values that RVM sets. Currently, you're sourcing RVM and then overwriting the modified PATH it creates. Depending on your startup file configuration, the following line should be placed last in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Don't modify your PATH after sourcing RVM unless you know what you're doing. Even then, you will need to make sure that you append or prepend the new PATH with the current PATH. For example, you could place something like the following after sourcing RVM:

```
PATH=$HOME/foo/bar:$PATH
```